# jQuery/JS doesn't work the same when in excluded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I got this jQuery code in the PHP file:

```
function loadkontakte(){
    $('#kontakte').load('kontakte.php',function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadkontakte();
setInterval (loadkontakte, 5000);
```

So kontakte.php is refreshed every 5 seconds and also instantly on pageload through `loadkontakte()`;

Now when I write this code into separate file **bla.js** in the same folder and include this file, the code works, not instantly but after 5 seconds, so `loadkontakte();` doesn't work any more, whats the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us how you've imported the JS file?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="bla.js"></script> under the library, as mentioned the code works, just not instantly but after and every 5 seconds. When the code is in the current PHP file, then it works ALSO instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the JS code inside the .php file, the code is under the `#kontakte` element while when you have it in a separate file, the script tag `<script src="bla.js"></script>` is before the `#kontakte` element?

If yes, this can explain why the JS code does not run instantly when the JS code is in an external file. If this is the case, you can do the following:

1. Put the `<script>` tag in the bottom of the page.
2. Or use the `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` event handler so that the code will execute after the page has loaded.

For the #2 scenario your `bla.js` could be:

```
function loadkontakte(){
    $('#kontakte').load('kontakte.php',function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadkontakte();
    setInterval (loadkontakte, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Glad I helped! I can't see any reason why you are getting so many downvotes... :(